# Confused about definability of a function in logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider language $L = \{ +\}$ and consider the $L$-structure $M =(\mathbb{N},+)$. I define $\{ 0 \}$ (**i.e., $0$ is the only number that satisfies the formula**) in two ways. One is, $\phi[x]= x+x \simeq x$, and the other one is $\phi = \exists x(x+x \simeq x)$. In the first one, $x$ is a free variable, while in the second one, $x$ is a bound variable. Is there a difference between these two formulas? What's the point for free variables? Please help me answer these two questions as I am very confused about writing formulas in first-order languages.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is just a sentence which happens to be true - it doesn't define $0$. $0$ is the unique *witness* to that sentence being true, but that's a different thing. In particular, note that "$0$ is the unique witness to the sentence "$\exists x(x=x+x)$"" is saying exactly that "the formula $x=x+x$ defines $0$."

A sentence is either true or false. A formula $\psi$ with $n$ free variables carves out a subset of $M^n$ (namely $\{(a_1, . . . , a_n): M\models \psi(a_1, . . . , a_n)\}$) - in particular a formula with one free variable carves out a subset of $M$. An element $a$ of $M$ is definable if there is some formula carving out $\{a\}$ - that is, if there is some $\psi(x)$ such that $M\models\forall x(\psi(x)\iff x=a)$. One of the motivations behind model theory is that if we care about a structure, we care about its definable elements, and its definable subsets, and the definable subsets of its Cartesian powers.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I still don't understand, what exactly is the difference between the first formula and the second formula (the latter one happens to be a sentence because it has no free variable). Both are just true and describe the same thing?

Comment: @HuyTruong No. A sentence is either "true" or "false" - it doesn't describe a *part of the model*. A formula is, really, neither true nor false because its meaning isn't determinate (there are free variables); any formula determines the part of the model consisting of those things you can 'plug in' and get a true formula. Sentences of the form "$\exists x\varphi(x)$" look like they're defining something, namely the set of $a$ such that $\varphi(a)$ holds, but really the *formula $\varphi(x)$* itself is defining this set; "$\exists x\varphi(x)$" is just saying that that set is nonempty!

Comment: Ok, so I can now understand that those two formulas do not mention 0, they just happen to be true in our structure M. (Is my understanding correct?) But exactly where they are different? The formula must mean something, so do they mean the same thing?

Comment: @HuyTruong No, a formula *doesn't* really mean anything on its own. That is, a formula doesn't say "such-and-such is true" - the presence of free variables means the formula is, basically, an "unfinished" sentence. Think about it this way: if I say "Fred is Swedish," that is a meaningful sentence, and is either true or false. If I say, "He is Swedish," and I don't give any clue who "he" refers to, then that's not really a meaningful sentence. An even better example might be if I just walked up and said ". . . is Swedish," but that's a bit weird. Does this help?

Comment: @HuyTruong And the *sentence* you mention is simply true in the structure, but the *formula* you mention does indeed define $0$: $0$ is the unique element of the structure which, when plugged into the formula in place of the free variable, yields a sentence true about the structure!